# youtube 4k video not list from youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

When I try to use the 4k video from youtube, I always can not get such high resolution stream. The highest resolution is HD.

for example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdwbYGe8pv8
```

I can only get below profile:

```
----> 22/1280x720/9/0/115
----> 43/640x360/99/0/0
----> 18/640x360/9/0/115
----> 5/426x240/7/0/0
----> 36/426x240/99/1/0
----> 17/256x144/99/1/0
```

That means the highest resolution is 1280x720 but not 4k video.

Anyone know if it's really a issue or I need to use other API to get 4k video?

Comment: Why the answers speak of downloading videos and youtube-dl ? what does this have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <...> 1080p support is gone - youtube removed 1080p downloads, only DASH would work - and we need a other way to get 1080p and above.

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/1261#issuecomment-26554531

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

- Install youtube-dl tool

  brew install youtube-dl
- Run below command to query stream information:

  youtube-dl -F http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMwpbfxY_Gc --verbose

output:

```
[info] Available formats for iNJdPyoqt8U:
format code  extension  resolution note
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  129k , m4a_dash container, aac  @128k (44100Hz), 4.72MiB
171          webm       audio only DASH audio  171k , audio@128k (44100Hz), 5.01MiB
141          m4a        audio only DASH audio  256k , m4a_dash container, aac  @256k (44100Hz), 9.38MiB
160          mp4        256x144    DASH video  111k , 15fps, video only, 4.01MiB
278          webm       256x144    DASH video  146k , webm container, VP9, 15fps, video only, 3.42MiB
133          mp4        426x240    DASH video  250k , 30fps, video only, 8.99MiB
242          webm       426x240    DASH video  301k , 30fps, video only, 6.73MiB
243          webm       640x360    DASH video  539k , 30fps, video only, 12.45MiB
134          mp4        640x360    DASH video  607k , 30fps, video only, 14.59MiB
244          webm       854x480    DASH video  985k , 30fps, video only, 22.64MiB
135          mp4        854x480    DASH video 1112k , 30fps, video only, 28.84MiB
247          webm       1280x720   DASH video 1933k , 30fps, video only, 45.20MiB
136          mp4        1280x720   DASH video 2219k , 30fps, video only, 56.87MiB
248          webm       1920x1080  DASH video 3244k , 30fps, video only, 76.72MiB
137          mp4        1920x1080  DASH video 4191k , 30fps, video only, 109.25MiB
264          mp4        2560x1440  DASH video 10096k , 30fps, video only, 275.62MiB
271          webm       2560x1440  DASH video 13837k , 30fps, video only, 245.05MiB
266          mp4        3840x2160  DASH video 22550k , h264, 30fps, video only, 771.23MiB
138          mp4        3840x2160  DASH video 24322k , 30fps, video only, 573.82MiB
313          webm       3840x2160  DASH video 26495k , VP9, 30fps, video only, 477.05MiB
17           3gp        176x144    
36           3gp        320x240    
5            flv        400x240    
43           webm       640x360    
18           mp4        640x360    
22           mp4        1280x720   (best)
```

- Run below command to download the video (138) and audio (141)

  youtube-dl -f 138+141  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNJdPyoqt8U

Then you will get the 4k video file.